# Как в коде поменять значения constraints для trailing и leading? iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Господа, как в коде поменять значения constraints для trailing и leading? (storyboard не могу использовать он нужен для другого таргета) Изменения размеров нормально принял, но встал не по центру, пытаюсь добавить trailing и leading -приложение падает.[image: constraints для trailing и leading]

Comment: Проверьте в IB, может ваша constraint имеет не верную ссылку. Второй вариант попробуйте убрать weak.

Comment: Да, в первую очередь полез бы в StoryBoard и проверил бы ссылку. Есть ли вообще связь IB с кодом.

Comment: Если вы решили свою проблему, то опишите её решение в виде ответа на свой вопрос (в большое поле ниже) и отметьте свой ответ как решение. Вопрос редактировать для этих целей не надо. Также размещайте код текстом, а не картинкой, чтобы его могли скопировать другие пользователи.

Comment: @terron Спасибо, поправил =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему довольно просто (как оказалось). В необходимом ViewController, делаем правки в функции viewWillLayoutSubviews (изначально конечно же создав нужные оутлеты)

```
//Outlets for constraints
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
//  @IBOutlet weak var searchBarBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

//Функция в которой можно менять значения constraints
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        searchBarTop.constant = 25
        searchBarTrailing.constant = 40
        searchBarLeading.constant = 40
        //  searchBarBottom.constant = 20
}
```